# __slots__ conflicts with a class variable in a generic class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, typing, slots

I've got conflicts between Python's typing system and `__slots__`. Here is a small reproducible example.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Sequence

T = TypeVar("T")

class TestGeneric(Sequence, Generic[T]):
    __slots__ = ("test",)

    def __init__(self, test: T):
        self.test = [test]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.test)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.test)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self.test

    def __getitem__(self, _):
        return self.test[0]
```

Now whenever I try to specify a content type, e.g.

```
V = TestGeneric[int]
```

I get

```
ValueError: 'test' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable
```

I use `Generics`  in classes without slots a lot, hence I think this error has to be linked to `__slots__`. Moreover, the same class works fine, if you remove the `__slots__`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say that this is a bug in the `typing` module, which does not properly take into account `__slots__` when creating new types.

This problem can be reproduced with this very short example:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...   __slots__ = ('my_member',)
... 
>>> type('MySubClass', (MyClass,), dict(MyClass.__dict__))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 'my_member' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable
```

Type call to `type()` above is the equivalent of what is happening behind the scenes in the `typing` module.

This exception is caused by the fact that when you use `__slots__`, the members you specify are automatically added into the type dict:

```
>>> MyClass.__slots__
['my_member']
>>> MyClass.__dict__
mappingproxy({..., 'my_member': <member 'my_member' of 'MyClass' objects>, ...})
```

When we do `type('MySubClass', (MyClass,), dict(MyClass.__dict__))`, we are passing `my_member` twice: once via `MyClass.__slots__`, once via `MyClass.__dict__`, and the type machinery is complaining about it.

There's not much you can do about it, other than avoiding using `__slots__` or calling `register()` instead of subclassing.

Comment: I thought it was a bug, but wanted to be sure. I've filed a report.

Comment: @EliKorvigo was this bug fixed ?

Comment: Yes, they've patched it.

Comment: Can anyone please link the bug report.